# Running an applet - Blocked by Security

Tags: java, html, security, applet

Basically, what I am trying to do is run an applet.

I made applet, tested it (offline, from Eclipse), exported .jar file and posted on dropbox.com. Then I made simple hmtl which should run that applet.

However I can't get pass the Java security (keep getting "**Application Blocked by Java Security**" error), even after adding dropbox to "Exception Site List" in Java Control Panel.

[image: Error Image]

[image: Java Control Panel]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            My Title v3.0
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <object width="480" height="360" data="MyNumber.jar" type="application/x-java-applet">
        <param name="codebase" value="https://www.dropbox.com/s/mz6y145mwdtge7r/MyNumber.jar?dl=0" />
        <param name="code" value="mynumber.online.MyNumberOnline />
        <param name="width" value="480" />
        <param name="height" value="360" />
        <param name="archive" value="MyNumber.jar" />
        </object>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to get past this?

Comment: Have you tried placing the HTML file in Dropbox as well?

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Answer (score 1):

You have to sign this applet with a certificate as the dialog says "identified by a certificate".

Comment: He is testing an applet. He is not going to pay money to sign it.

Comment: self signed certificates should also work, the client just have to accept it

Comment: Okay, then. Perhaps you should show him how to do this.

Comment: Is not that simple to write it here but heres a link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/rsa_signing.html

Comment: *"self signed certificates should also work,.."* Not for some time now, no. Oracle has cracked down on security & since a 'self signed' certificate can be made up by anyone, they will not launch unless the default JRE security level has been dropped far below where it should be. Plus one for the rest of your advice.